# 2 Computers 1 Database 1 fast 1 slow

Tags: sql-server

- Computer A is Intel i7-5820K, 6 cores, 12 threads, 32G RAM
- Computer B is Intel i7-6700K, 4 cores, 8 threads, 64G RAM

I installed SQL Server 2014 Express + Management Studio on both computers.

I restore `Database1` from Computer A to Computer B.

Both databases are on their respective hard drive.

- Query1 on computer A = 00:33
- Query1 on computer B = 03:23

I check all the server properties and connections properties and they are all the same.

Someone would know why my Computer A is 6 times faster than my computer B?

Thank you

Comment: Rebuild statistics

Comment: Are both machines on the same network and connected at the same speed?

Comment: Do you get the same execution plans on both machines?

Comment: sounds like 2 Computers 2 Databases

Comment: What do the disk drives look like?  RAID, SATA, SSD?

Comment: I rebuilt statistics no change

Comment: 2 computers are in 2 different locations but not in network
Small database querying csv files on hard drive

Comment: If I back up the database from computer A and I restore it on Computer B, am I right to assume it's the same database?

Comment: Both drive Western Digital SATA

Comment: Antivirus on either?   How about contention (are there other DBs running on either machine which may be pegging the RAM or CPU)?

Comment: No third party anti-virus, both machine on Windows 10

Comment: I have only 1 database and run only sql server management studio to do the test

Comment: What do you mean the database is "querying CSV files on hard drive"? Is this some `OPENQUERY` query or similar?

Comment: select *  FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database='

Comment: You could try looking at the waitstats in SQL Server but I suspect it might not be very illuminating in this case. It might just say the slower machine is waiting on `OLEDB` more. In which case maybe running a Windows performance toolkit trace on both machines whilst the queries are running might shed some light on things.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded Windows Assesment and Deployment kit I'll see what it does on both machine while running the query and I'll be back with results shortly

Comment: Battery backed storage or not: Makes a huge difference.

Comment: You're running an OPENQUERY on an Access database? Where is it situated? That probably explains it all. Please post this kind of info early on. Please post the full SELECT statement in your answer. i.e. if its running on a remote Access database that would explain a lot.

Comment: SQL Server Database. The Query gets rows from excel files on hard drive. All the files are the same on each computers and the Database is the same since I restored it from a backup on the other one.

Comment: Neither computer has battery backed storage, only internal hard drive, both very recent

Comment: So in both cases the files are _local_ to the SQL Server? Is it just a simple select with OPENQUERY or is it also joining to local data? You really need to compare query plans, post the actual query and clarify is it using excel or csv? It's all pretty hazy.

Comment: Yes, both local. Using excel files local (they are the same because they are synchronized with Dropbox). Exact same OPENROWSET Query. The whole query is quite long to post here and it is the exact same query on each computer.

Comment: @MartinSmith seems to be on the right path. I noticed that the slower computer had only Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server while the other computer had 11 and 13. I installed 13 and that improve the speed to 01:23. It still slower but it seems to be related to ODBC